# upload file to server side failed with ajax

Tags: ajax, reactjs

I'm using react dropzone component (https://github.com/felixrieseberg/React-Dropzone-Component) to upload an image to server. The server script is working properly, I've tested it with postman.

The API need a param that receive the file. I got an error of the file field is missing, so I doubht I'm passing the correct thing. I do console.log(file); I'm seeing below value

[image]

Comment: Please share exact error text.

Comment: @elmeister missing file, but I already passed in file.

Comment: What is error callback message https://github.com/felixrieseberg/React-Dropzone-Component#callbacks? Your server-side code is the same as here https://github.com/felixrieseberg/React-Dropzone-Component/blob/master/example/src-server/multerImpl.js?

Comment: I have no control over server side code. I tested it via postman, it has no problem.

Comment: You should compare POST data for postman and dropzone and fix the difference. Sorry, I am not able to determine the problem only by attached screenshot without details.

Comment: @elmeister I fixed it, now I have problem with progress loader. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43292679/dropzone-js-show-progress-bar-using-manual-ajax-call