# dropzone.js show progress bar using manual ajax call

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs

Try to integrate react with dropzone using this library https://github.com/felixrieseberg/React-Dropzone-Component but no luck, stuck for hours. File is uploaded but couldn't see any progress bar.

```
export default class PhotoUpload extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.dropzone = null;

        // For a full list of possible configurations,
        // please consult http://www.dropzonejs.com/#configuration
        this.djsConfig = {
            acceptedFiles: "image/jpeg,image/png,image/gif",
            addRemoveLinks: true,
            autoProcessQueue: false
        };

        this.componentConfig = {
            iconFiletypes: ['.jpg', '.png', '.gif'],
            showFiletypeIcon: true,
            postUrl: 'no-url'
        };

        this.callback = (file) => {

            this.dropzone.processQueue();

            myApi.upload(file).then((e) => {
                console.log('done upload '+e.filename+' to server');
            })
        }
    }

    render() {
        const config = this.componentConfig;
        const djsConfig = this.djsConfig;

        // For a list of all possible events (there are many), see README.md!
        const eventHandlers = {
            init: dz => this.dropzone = dz,
            drop: this.callback,
            addedfile: this.callback,
        }

        return <DropzoneComponent config={config} eventHandlers={eventHandlers} djsConfig={djsConfig} />
    }
}
```

Apparently, this line of code doesn't work : `this.dropzone.processQueue();`

Comment: `processQueue` is designed to post data using form action url, while you upload it via `myApi.upload`. These flows aren't connected. `postUrl: 'no-url'` - move your myApi url here to be able to see progress bar.

Comment: You can call http://www.dropzonejs.com/#event-uploadprogress event to update progress manually.

Comment: @elmeister where?

Comment: @elmeister nope, I have token and role auth in my header and it's better to separate it.

Comment: No problem, show your own progress bar then.

Comment: @elmeister what are you trying to say? the build in progress bar count the progress, you're saying simply show a fake progress bar?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/140234/discussion-between-elmeister-and-alex-yong).